# Angular 7 blur and click not working same time

Tags: angular6, angular7, dom-events

In my form contains textbox and button. I am doing some operation in textbox (blur) event and button (click) event.

Let's assume:

user enter some text in textbox and click the button. (blur) event invoked but (click) event not invoking.

note : "at the time of clicking the button focus should be in textbox."

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4h9pi

blur event alert is coming but click event alert not coming.

### Scenario

In onblur event I make the service call to save that field value. In onClick event I have to save all the fields data. If cursor focus one of the textbox then user click the save button. First I have save the field after finishing the first call, make the second call to save all the data. Do not call the service parallel. I want to call one by one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 7 click event not working after blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58149457/angular-7-click-event-not-working-after-blur)

Comment: please refrain posting the same question multiple time

Answer (score 0):

Remove `alert` with `console.log` or other relevant code. `alert` will be triggered as as soon as focus is lost from the input even before the button is clicked. So two event is not firing simultaneously

[stackblitz](https://angular-b4h9pi.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Is it possible to fire two event simultaneously. because i want to handle this scenario , in onblur event i make the service call to save that field value. in onClick event i have to save all the fields data. if cursor focus one of the textbox then user click the save button. first i have save the field after finishing the first call, make the second call to save all the data.  do not call the service parallel. i want to call one by one

Answer (score 0):

Both events are indeed firing. You can confirm by changing your `alert` calls to `console.log`. I believe the browser is likely just blocking multiple alert dialogs.

---

**Update to answer your comment:**

You say you want them to fire simultaneously and then you say you don’t so I’m having trouble understanding your needs.

I can tell you this though. The blur event fires, then the click event fires. You should be able to handle whatever you need to in those handlers with that knowledge.

If you need to wait for your blur handler to come back with a response before sending that data along with your click handler, you could theoretically set a variable like

```
this.blurRequestLoading=true
```

That way, instead of firing the click request, if `blurRequestLoading` is `true`, you could set a `this.clickEventPendingBlurResponse=true`.

Then when the blurResponse comes back, you can set `blurRequestLoading` back to `false`, and if `clickEventPendingBlurResponse` is `true`, fire the clickEvent manually within the response handler, and set `clickEventPendingBlurResponse` back to `false`.

Comment: Is it possible to fire two event simultaneously. because i want to handle this scenario , in onblur event i make the service call to save that field value. in onClick event i have to save all the fields data. if cursor focus one of the textbox then user click the save button. first i have save the field after finishing the first call, make the second call to save all the data. do not call the service parallel. i want to call one by one

Comment: I’ve updated my answer to try to help you with your question.

Comment: Hi thanks for your time and effort, i did one logic to sequence the event, please suggest me is this code in production level.

sample code base: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czxn9o

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfr86y If you need it to fire on blur, you could track if you're currently focused on a field instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for your time and effort, i did one logic to sequence the event, please suggest me is this code in production level.

sample code base: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czxn9o